# ld: framework not found DiskArbitration for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone advise where I can get DiskArbitration framework for iOS? I have some 3rd party framework in the app and when I compile, I am getting following error

```
ld: framework not found DiskArbitration for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you are add DiskArbitration framework & set value: go to build setting -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags = $(inherited)

Comment: It is already there.. but does not help. I also tried copying DiskArbitration from OS X into X-Code as well. Still same error. Any other ideas?